# cp won't work on current bash script's directory

Tags: bash, file-copy

I'm trying to copy some files from current directory in a bash script but the problem is that the `cp` command doesn't work with the current directory. I can use the following command without any problem on Backtrack 5 (based on Ubuntu) but not in Kali linux (based on Debian):

```
cp -f -v *.{html,txt,php} /var/www/
```

I can execute this command directly from the terminal by first changing directory to the directory where these files are. But using script I get the following error:

```
cp -f -v *.{html,txt,php} /var/www/
cp: cannot stat `*.{html,txt,php}': No such file or directory
```

Again I have no problem with this command in the script when I use Ubuntu.

Comment: Likely down to `cp` version. That syntax doesn't look like POSIX to me.

Comment: it's related to your shell and globbing.

Answer (score 3):

Your script interpreter is set to `/bin/sh`.  On the system that expands the braced list, you are using the Bourne Again shell as `/bin/sh`.  On the system that treats the braces as ordinary (non-meta) characters, and complains that the wildcard doesn't match anything, you are using the Debian Almquist shell as `/bin/sh`.  Your interactive login shell is almost certainly explicitly `/bin/bash` on both systems.

If you are going to use such extensions to the POSIX shell language in a script, you must set the script interpreter to be the actual name of a shell that supports them.  Conversely, if you are going to use `/bin/sh` as a script interpreter across diverse systems you should stick strictly to shell syntax that is POSIX-conformant.

## Further reading

- https://superuser.com/a/696310/38062
- *[dash as `/bin/sh`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)*.  Ubuntu wiki.
- *[dash as `/bin/sh`](https://wiki.debian.org/DashAsBinSh)*.  Debian wiki.
- *[bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)*.  Greg's wiki.
- ["Word Expansions"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06).  *Shell Command Language*.  IEEE Std 1003.1.  Issue 7.  The Open Group.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `` cannot stat `*.{html,txt,php}' `` from `cp` indicates that either:

- No matching file exists, or
- You are using a shell that doesn't do brace expansion.

Which shell are you using on the system where the command fails? If it isn't bash but instead sh or dash, then that may explain what you are seeing. You could try giving your command `*.html *.txt *.php` instead of the brace pattern.

Comment: I use `sh` shell (.sh and bin/sh) . using separated extensions works but also I get some errors with `-e` parameter of `echo` (or maybe `read`, I don't remember).

Comment: Ok, I used `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` and now, it's working. but do I count on it? is it stable and won't make any future problems?

Comment: You can count on bash having this behavior; it is fully documented (search for "Brace Expansion" in the bash man page. As for `echo -e`, it's also documented when using the bash built-in; POSIX echo doesn't support `-e` and will print it verbatim.